# Invalid password? when sending iOS debug build on new machine

Tags: codenameone

We are having the following problems :

An existing CN1 project is working fine on **machine A (Windows)** and we can send iOS builds to the server.

Now we also want to work on the project on **machine B (MacOS)** but we cannot get this to work.

We keep getting a build error on the server.
While we use the same certificates, provisioning profiles and login settings.

The error log shows a possible problem with a password (see below).
We put an echo statement in `build.xml` to echo the password and it is correct.
So what can be the problem?

Below is the last part of the error log:

> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Maximus.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
>   Sending stats
>   Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.
>
> [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
>   Process return code is 0
>   openssl pkcs12 -in [password redacted] -out cert.crt.pem -password pass:passwordHidden -passout pass:password
>   Process return code is 0
>   Mac verify error: **invalid password?**
>   Process return code is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password for the certificate in codenameone_settings.properties was broken somehow in the other machine. This has nothing to do with your account.

Compare both `codenameone_settings.properties` files also make sure the password isn't defined globally in which case you might need to redefine it. To be clear I'm referring to one or both of the `ios.certificatePassword` values in the settings.